# document.title doesn't get the page title in Analytics event tracking

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

I am using this line to fire an event in order to see on what page people scrolled down

```
docTitle: window.document.title
...
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll', window.docTitle, 'scrolled']);
```

This work very well for the Asynchronous Syntax (ga.js) and the page title shows up in Analytics, but when I want to do the same for analytics.js with this

```
docTitle: window.document.title
...
ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll', window.docTitle, 'scrolled');
```

I don't get the page titles but only see 'window.docTitle'

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: why not use document.title directly in your ga() call?

Comment: There are some functions where I need it to be like this, but for this line I could try to use only document.title. I'll let you know tomorrow.

Comment: What stupid of me! The online and local version weren't the same. I had written 'window.docTitle' in stead of window.docTitle. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. So stupid...